# Select a value from dropdown on IE page via VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to select a value from a dropdown on a IE page.

I have tried a lot of methods. It doesn't do anything.

Source code of the drop down:
[image: source code of the drop down]

Codes I have tried, to select the value with "EVR" (there is only one value in the drop down):

```
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:06 AM#

IE.Visible = True

'IE.document.getElementById("fileOnlineReturnTaxType").Value = "EVR"

'IE.document.getElementsByName("taxType").Value = "84"

   'Set oSelect = IE.document.getElementById("fileOnlineReturnTaxType")
    '    oSelect.Focus
     '   oSelect.selectedIndex = 1
      '  oSelect.FireEvent "onchange"

 'IE.document.getElementById("fileOnlineReturnTaxType").Click


  'Set Link3 = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")

   ' For Each t In Link3
          ' If t.innerText = "Select a tax type..." Then
          ' MsgBox (t.innerText)
           '   t.Click
            '  Exit For
           'End If
          'Next t
```

Comment: What are the values of `IE.document.getElementsByName("taxType").Value` at debug?  Is the value "Select Tax Type"?  Look at Microsoft Internet Controls and HTML library, you can then set the object properly so, you can put the drop down in an object and debug a little better.

Comment: hi when I try : test = IE.document.getElementsByName("taxType")(0).Value then it will have then test = "" en with  test = IE.document.getElementsByName("taxType")(1).Value it has this error: object variable or with block variable not set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a change event and firing that

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "url"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim event_onChange As Object
        Set event_onChange = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False

        With .document.querySelector("#fileOnlineReturnTaxType")
            .selectedIndex = 1
            .FireEvent "onchange"
            .dispatchEvent event_onChange
        End With
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: wow I dont see the selected value in the dropdown box but it works!!!! Thank you very muchhh! I searched for this part for hours!